# How to sort after join and groupby

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

How do I sort after join and groupby? How do I order by field `ps.end`?

```
var query =
    from p in _productRepository.Table
    join ps in _productScheduleRepository.Table on p.Id equals ps.ProductId
    where p.Published &&
    !p.Deleted &&
    p.ShowOnHomePage &&
    !ps.IsUsage && ps.Start <= DateTime.Now && ps.End >= DateTime.Now
    group p by p.Id into Grouped
    select Grouped.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To order the items in the group, just call `OrderBy`:

```
var query = from p in _productRepository.Table
    join ps in _productScheduleRepository.Table on p.Id equals ps.ProductId
    where ...
    group new{ p, ps } by p.Id into Grouped
    select Grouped.OrderBy(pair => pair.ps.end).FirstOrDefault().p;
```

Comment: not access to field ps.end !!! ps.end is field of _productScheduleRepository.Table *** joined ***

Comment: @user3569283 Then you'll need to group on both values, rather than just the one.

Comment: ps.ProductId is foreign key for _productRepository.Table means relation is iCollection ps (is SelectMany) not access by Grouped.OrderBy(pair => pair.ps.end) !!

Comment: When you did an inner join you flattened that relationship into a sequence of pairs, rather than a pair with a collection of matching values (which is what you would have gotten from a `GroupJoin`, had you used it instead).